# Applying function to pandas dataframe column after str.findall

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I have such a dataframe `df` with two columns:

```
Col1 Col2
'abc-def-ghi' 1
'abc-opq-rst' 2
```

I created a new column `Col3` like this:

```
df['Col3'] = df['Col1'].str.findall('abc', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

And got such a dataframe afterwards:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
'abc-def-ghi' 1 [abc]
'abc-opq-rst' 2 [abc]
```

What I want to do now is to create a new column `Col4` where I get a one if Col3 contains `'abc'` and otherwise zero.

I tried to do this with a function:

```
def f(row):
    if row['Col3'] == '[abc]':
        val = 1
    else:
        val = 0
    return val
```

And applied this to my pandas dataframe:

```
df['Col4'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

But I only get 0, also in column that contain 'abc'. I think there is something wrong with my if-statement.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do

```
df['Col4'] = df.Col3.astype(bool).astype(int)
```